# Xamarin ios custom WkWebViewRenderer Scrolled event

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I'm changing the WebViewRenderer to WkWebViewRenderer in My Xamarin Forms app. I earlier had the Scrolled method which I override to detect scrolled to end. But no such method is available in the WkWebViewRenderer. How else can this be implemented?

```
public override void Scrolled(UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        base.Scrolled(scrollView);
        float y1 = (float)scrollView.ContentOffset.Y;
        if ((this.Element as CustomWebview).ScrolledToEnd == false)
        {
            if ((scrollView.ContentSize.Height - 20) < (y1 + this.Element.Height))
            {
                (this.Element as CustomWebview).ScrolledToEnd = true;
                if ((this.Element as CustomWebview).ScrollToEndDelegate != null)
                {
                    (this.Element as CustomWebview).ScrollToEndDelegate.Invoke(true);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured that now instead of the Scrolled method, we can now use The scrolled event inside the ScrollView property of WkWebView. This works for me:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        base.ScrollView.Scrolled += ScrollDetect;
    }

    private void ScrollDetect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```